# Right choice of data type for UUID as primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, primary-key, sqldatatypes

**Prior Conditions are**

> 1. Table will have data in billions
> 2. Table will have secondary indexes
> 3. Table's primary key will be a foreign key of another table.
> 4. Table will have a heavy data (another column may be Text).

Primary Key must be Unique, cause my database is replicated over machine's that's why I am choosing UUID.

PS: space is also a concern so I guess Varchar(36) might be the bad idea

Comment: CHAR(36) with a latin1 column collation is the best available option MySQL has to offer when storing UUID's

Comment: "Primary Key must be Unique, cause my database is replicated over machine's that's why I am choosing UUID." PRIMARY KEY's are also replicated onto other machines.. And besides a unsigned BIGINT can also hold   2^64-1 values should be plenty unique id's..

Comment: For Postgres use `uuid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with `BINARY(16)`.  (16 bytes is better than 37.)

But UUIDs are hopelessly inefficient for huge tables.  (I assume your billion-row table will not fit in RAM.)

I discuss those and more issues in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Answer (score 1):

I would go for BINARY(16). If you want to use CHAR then CHAR(32) is large enough without the hyphens, but BINARY is smaller and faster.

Comment: To use `CHAR(32)`, remember to have `ASCII` encoding for the column.